# I want to display last login time in php

Tags: php

To display last login time..

i want to save login time to database in processlogin  page...and fetch that for next time in login page..

i got current date and time correctly by using

```
$dt=date("m/d/y G:i:s<br>", time());
```

nd now i want to save `$dt` to database for that i have write below code

```
$qdt = "select * from lastlogin";
    $rsLogin1 = $objdb->select($qdt);
if(rsLogin1 != null)
{
 $qaa = "update lastlogin set last='".$dt."'";
 $rsLogin12 = $objdb->select($qaa);
}
else
{
  $qa = "insert into lastlogin(last) values('".$dt."')";
    $rsLogin1 = $objdb->select($qa); 
}
```

when this page is running it show me

`update lastlogin set last='11/08/12 15:00:07'` with statment wrong query

and when i copy and paste same query to my sql query...it give me correct result..

Can any one please help me that where i am wrong or what i have to do to solve this..

my database name is `lastlogin` and field is last which is `varchar(200)`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean your table name is `lastlogin?`

Comment: What is your result and what should be the correct result?

Comment: unrelated note.  I think readability improves when you embed php variables in strings using double quotes.  php allows it and will render it correctly, such as: "update lastlogin set last='$dt'"; You don't need to bother with the string appending so it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're adding more work than is necessary.  One way to store last login time would be to utilize the MySQL column type `timestamp` and set the default value to `current_timestamp`.  This way you're not needing to calculate anything, and it will be populated for you.  From there, just manipulate it from the database with the `date()` function.

Comment: +1 Just a note: That only works if you only have one column you'd like to default to the current time stamp otherwise MySQL doesn't allow it.

Comment: In his application, I don't see that becoming an issue...  But, noted.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the time format according to MYSQL or what ever DB
yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss
Why to use VARCHAR(200) for dateand time , USe datetime for dates and time in DB

AND you did not specify the where CLAUSE in Sql, It will update all records in DB so try like that

update lastlogin set last='2012-11-08 15:00:07'  WHERE ID= ???